# Error while converting Date column to date.time format in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert the date column to the proper date time format via `pd.date.time` but getting an error: `ValueError: time data "1/1/1900" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d", at position 1874.` Getting this error again and again and tried the below code but didn't work. Any suggestions will be appreciated. I know there are similar questions already posted here but I wanted to try something like this.

Data sample:

```
            dt  AverageTemperature  AverageTemperatureUncertainty   City  \
0   1743-11-01                6.07                           1.74  Århus   
1   1743-12-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
2   1744-01-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
3   1744-02-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
4   1744-03-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
5   1744-04-01                5.79                           3.62  Århus   
6   1744-05-01               10.64                           1.28  Århus   
7   1744-06-01               14.05                           1.35  Århus   
8   1744-07-01               16.08                           1.40  Århus   
9   1744-08-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
10  1744-09-01               12.78                           1.45  Århus   
11  1744-10-01                7.95                           1.63  Århus   
12  1744-11-01                4.64                           1.30  Århus   
13  1744-12-01                0.12                           1.76  Århus   
14  1745-01-01               -1.33                           1.64  Århus   
15  1745-02-01               -2.73                           1.36  Århus   
16  1745-03-01                0.13                           1.09  Århus   
17  1745-04-01                4.04                           1.14  Århus   
18  1745-05-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
19  1745-06-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
20  1745-07-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
21  1745-08-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
22  1745-09-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
23  1745-10-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
24  1745-11-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
25  1745-12-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
26  1746-01-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
27  1746-02-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
28  1746-03-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   
29  1746-04-01                 NaN                            NaN  Århus   

    Country Latitude Longitude  
0   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
1   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
2   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
3   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
4   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
5   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
6   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
7   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
8   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
9   Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
10  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
11  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
12  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
13  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
14  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
15  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
16  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
17  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
18  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
19  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
20  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
21  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
22  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
23  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
24  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
25  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
26  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
27  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
28  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E  
29  Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
```

Code:

```
# Specify the path to your CSV file
csv_file = "Data.csv"

# Read the CSV file and create a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Convert 'dt' column to datetime type, inferring the format
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], infer_datetime_format=True)

# Extract year from 'dt' column
df['Year'] = df['dt'].dt.year

# Remove rows with NaN values
df = df.dropna()

# Set the display options for pandas
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)

# Print the number of NaN values removed
nan_count = df.isnull().sum().sum()
print("Number of NaN values removed:", nan_count)

# Print the summary of the DataFrame
print("Summary of the DataFrame:")
print(df.describe())

# Print the updated DataFrame
print("Updated DataFrame:")
print(df)
```

Comment: Does position 1874 exists in your dataframe? What is the date in that position?

Comment: Yes, I am using this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data?select=GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv

Comment: did you try with `infer_datetime_format=False`? "1/1/1900" is "%m/%d/%Y" OR "%d/%m/%Y", not "%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: I've failed to reproduce the issue with the data @talhaasif mentions. Are you sure the "Data.csv" is the same as one of files of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same file.